# Property or method to force ExtJS 4.2.1 grid to adjust its height automatically

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2, extjs-grid

I have a simple grid developed using ExtJs 4.2.1 framework. The grid is having one bottom bar (bbar).
 Problem: Horizontal scrollbar is not visible due to the bottom bar (its hidden behind the bottom bar). If I set the height of the grid using grid.setHeight(), I can see the horizontal scroll bar. Is there anyway to tell the grid to adjust its height based on scroll bar visibility?

Earlier I used following code to adjust the height based on scroll bar visibility. But this option is not working in ExtJs 4.2.1.

```
 if (grid.view.getWidth() < parseFloat(grid.view.getEl().dom.children[0].style.width)) {
        alert('horizontal scroll is present');
  if (grid.view.getHeight() < parseFloat(grid.view.getEl().dom.children[0].scrollHeight)) {
            alert('vertical scroll is present');
    }
```

Please provide your suggestions.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can try autoHeight = true or
try the below approach

layout: 'fit',
  align: 'stretch',
  items: [{ xtype: 'yourgrid'}]

ie, the containers layout of your grid use fit and align stretch

Answer (score -1):

use autoHeight:true, config in the grid

Comment: -1, autoHeight and is a deprecated config. Simply omitting a calculated/fixed size is enough.